# How to disable all validations for plain text in VS code

Tags: validation, visual-studio-code, plaintext, disable

I am building a Laravel project with VS Code on Ubuntu 18.04.
I've installed a couple of extensions to help me with the syntax.

I also have a few .txt files in the same workspace that I use for miscellaneous notes. All the content of my .txt files gets red wavy underlining.

Do you know how to disable all the spell-check and validation only for my plain text files?

I've read these posts, about disabling PHP and CSS validation, but that didn't help my case.

[How to disable PHP validation in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847489/how-to-disable-php-validation-in-visual-studio-code)

[Disable wavy underline in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454967/disable-wavy-underline-in-vs-code)

my extensions list

code --install-extension ban.spellright

code --install-extension bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

code --install-extension cjhowe7.laravel-blade

code --install-extension dacoto.laravel-easy-blade-snippets

code --install-extension felixfbecker.php-debug

code --install-extension felixfbecker.php-intellisense

code --install-extension ikappas.phpcs

code --install-extension onecentlin.laravel-blade

code --install-extension onecentlin.laravel5-snippets

code --install-extension streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sort of figured it out for myself now that I'm more familiar with VS Code.

In my case, every underlined word is related to a warning message.
Those warnings are counted in [My status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fryRM.png) (located at the low left corner).

I can see the full warning messages in the "Problems" section

- by clicking on the status bar icon
- or by using the hotkey for Problems (Ctrl+Shift+M)

When I saw the full messages it was obvious that the [Spell Right](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ban.spellright)
extension was doing all the underlining.
For now, I just uninstalled it.

Comment: for me this was not only LanguageTool but also the English language support for LanguageTool - uninstalled them both.

Answer (score -1):

change your file extension to TXT it wont validate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't change anything : (

Comment: Uninstall any spelling checker you have.